# How do you vertically center legends using Google Charts API?

Tags: graph, charts, google-visualization

I'm having trouble vertically centering the legends in Google Charts Pie Graph.  Anyone have previously experience?  Or is the best bet to code my own pie graph?

Thanks in advance,
Walker

Comment: Are you using the [static image API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/pie_charts.html)?

Comment: I believe so - that link is to exactly what we used.  2D pie chart.

Comment: This is what we were using: http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/piechart.html -> and using the parameters listed for styling.

Answer (score 12):

Use the following in the charts option:

```
 var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
      legend: {'position':'top','alignment':'center'},
    };
```

The "legend.alignment" can be found in this documentation:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart?csw=1

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the chdlp and chma parameters?

Comment: nope, didn't see that - looking into it now.  This is the exactly how we want the legend to align, but I don't see any parameter that indicates centering.

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/piechart.html <- those are the parameters we were using / I was aware of.